# Dictionary with two items with the same name

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am trying to retrieve the 'price' for the 'WIN_ODDS_BSP' so '10.09'. I am not sure if 'productType' is a dictionary or an item. If it is an item, how do I access the 'markets' dictionary where there are two items with the same name ('productType')?

Here is a sample of the json:

```
"markets":[{"productType":"WIN_ODDS_BSP","price":10.09,"reductionFactor":8.33},{"productType":"PLACE_ODDS_BSP","price":2.92,"reductionFactor":13.85}],"bestNZTote":0},
```

Here is my code:

```
for runner in json2['runners']:
    for market in runner['markets']:
        data.append((runner['runnerName'],runner.get('placedResult'),market.get('price'),runner.get('bestTote')))
```

Comment: `markets` is not a dictionary; it is a list of dictionaries and each dictionary has a key named `productType`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass an 'if' condition to each of the items in **markets**.

```
for market in runner['markets']:
  if market['productType'] == 'WIN_ODDS_BSP':
    data.append(market['price'])
```

.